# "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed." while working with ‘Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0’ provider

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, ms-office

**Configuration**

Excel 2013 (64 bit), OS (64 bit), built in x86 platform

**Issue**

This question **can be duplicate**, but i am unable to find the proper solution.

I am developing winform where i am trying to connect with the access database. In my system, everything works fine (64 bit os, 32 bit excel). But client is having above configuration. While connecting, i am getting exception as, **"Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."**, i have referred mainly 2 links:

1. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734
2. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

but both failed to worked. Still i am getting same exception. Is there any other solution which i can try? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how does your connection string look like?

Comment: Connection string : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=/****path of mdb file*****/;Persist Security Info=False

Comment: Compiling for x86 plattform means you run your app as 32 bit process, having excel and oledb drivers also as 32 bit is fine, but your client has 64 bit excel and oledb drivers, which can not be accessed from 32 bit application, imho. either install 32 bit excel at your client or depoloy a x64 platform version of your application to the client

Comment: @ Alexander Powolozki, apart from this, is there any drivers available which i  can install which can enable to communication between the two? like AccessDatabaseEngine.exe we can install to achieve in some cases?

Comment: Also can you please tell me what is the reason of above link is not working?